# Grout has gone hard and I have not finished can I add something to it to soften grout to finish the job

Tags: grout

As title says need to soften up the grout to finish job

Comment: No, you probably need to use a grout saw to remove the half-done parts and you definitely need to mix a new batch of grout.

Answer (score 4):

No.  Grout is basically a form of concrete.  If this technology existed then when the government needed to redo roads they would just add this magical potion and road would be redone.  A small batch of grout mixed properly only has a usable time of a few hours.  Once it even gets even a little stiff it is done.

Answer (score 0):

**Couple of tips I use to prolong grout setting time:**

- Ensure the grout lines are as clean and dust free as possible.
- Damping the grout lines with a spray bottle (very lightly)
- Use as clean a water you can get your hands on (areas with hard tap water can accelerate setting time. I just boil the kettle and then let it cool completely.
- My favourite tip is a little extra work but worth the effort. I get a large flexi-tub bucket which I fill 1/4 of tap water then I add as much ice/ice packs as I can get my hands on. I then put the grout bucket in this, pour in the required amount of kettle water for the grout, let it cool then mix in the grout. You then keep the mixed grout in the flexi-tub whilst grouting. This has helped double setting time (sometimes longer) for me and I have never had any grout issues once set that I'm aware off.